# Save the passed value from python in html select tag form

Tags: python, html, flask

I am passing a string value to select tag in html form and its working properly. But when I load the page again or run the script again, the previously passed values are not shown in drop down list.

In html form, I am passing value like this:

```
<option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
```

In python:

```
x = "Example" 
return render_template('example.html', x=x)
```

can anyone please let me know how to save this value so that it is available for selection in drop down list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could set a list, append new option values in it and then pass the list to your html template. Something like this;

```
# app.py
    optionsList = []
    optionsList.append('Example')
    optionsList.append('Example2')
    return render_template('example.html', options=optionsList)

# example.html
    {% if options %}
        <select name="foo" id="foo">
        {% for option in options %}
            <option value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this but its not saving the value. If I run the python script again the previously passed value is not available in select tag form...

Comment: And that's normal as you kill the service by restarting the python script. You could try to save the option values onto a database. Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here by restarting the script though. If you could provide more information that would be really helpful :)

Comment: Its part of some visualization.. User runs the script before loading the visualization.. There is no database available.. Is there any way to achieve it without using database?

Comment: I think you can try using session and cookies and stuff for that instead of a database.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are three possible ways to achieve this:

1. Use session variables/cookies

Try saving the option list as a variable in a cookie on the client side. This will also work even if you reload your python script. Here's a link to get you started: https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-sessions/

2. Use forwarding url values

You can use the url as a place to store values for the options list. For example, the following coarse code logic does the same (just modifying the code provided by [HRSArgyropoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68070936/11426625)):

```py
# example.html
 {% if options %}
    <select name="foo" id="foo">
    {% for option in options %}
        <option value="{{ option }}">{{ option }}</option>
        <a href={{url_for('xyz', options=options_list, new_option=option)}}></a>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endif %}

# app.py
@app.route("/xyz/<str:options_list>/<str:new_option>)", methods=('get', 'post'))
def xyz(options_list, new_option)
    options_list.append(new_option)
    return render_template('example.html', options=options_list)
```

3. Use database

This is pretty straight forward, just use a sqlite database on the backend to store values as a list. Here's a link to get you started: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/patterns/sqlite3/